# How to execute sql TRIGGER automatically after every 5 seconds in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, eventtrigger

I want to make a stored procedure by which a Triggers will automatically execute after 5 seconds to check/show whether new row is updated or not.

I have a table called 'Inbox' in Database. I made a trigger for this whenever data in inserted in table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_Inbox_ForInsert
ON Inbox
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM inserted
END
```

I just want this trigger to execute itself after 5 seconds

Comment: That's not how a trigger works. When someone inserts a row into the table, the trigger will be executed.

Comment: You could add a timestamp to your table, and have an UPDATE trigger that checks if the updated row is newer than 5 seconds.

Comment: You can run a job [every 10 seconds](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/f4e1ccbf-4932-4330-8706-86420a077c39/runing-a-sql-agent-job-every-5-second?forum=sqldatabaseengine), but I question your requirements.  They may make more sense if you explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Not sure why you want to use a trigger here at all. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: Check/show to whom? If you need to refresh data in an application when changes are made, consider `SqlDependnecy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how triggers work... They are run after a transaction is carried out on the object they are attached to.

If you want something to run every X time interval, look into SQL Server Agent Jobs instead